# A phantom linebreak with Polyglossia and BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia, windycity

**Edit**: it is [a problem with BibLaTeX](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1041). The good news is that there appears to be a fix coming soon—and you can add it to your preamble now. Thanks, [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for the pointer.

A picture is worth a thousand words. If you check the screenshot below you will see that there is a strange linebreak right after an opening parenthesis. This phantom linebreak happens the first time I use `\textgreek` to enter ancient Greek text. This unwanted linebreak never appears again. (You can see that from the image and MWE: I include the exact same sentence later in the paragraph, but there is no phantom linebreak the second time.) I cannot figure out exactly what causes the linebreak, but I think I've narrowed it down to an interaction (?) Polyglossia and [Windy City](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity).

[image]

My MWE is below. After adding and removing things, the problem seems to be Polyglossia and [Windy City](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity). If I remove Windy City, the problem goes away. If I swap Babel for Polyglossia, the problem goes away. But I don't want to remove either Windy City or Polyglossia if I can avoid it. If it's a bug on one side or the other, I am happy to file a bug report, but I am not sure where to start looking.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}

\usepackage[nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchLowercase]{GFS Neohellenic}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=windycity,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{plato.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Socratic Irony}

Kreuz cites Aristotle for testimony about Socratic irony.
Aristotle mentions Socrates in Book 4 of \textit{Nichomachean Ethics} while he is discussing the virtue concerning truthfulness about one's abilities.
This (unnamed) virtue, says Aristotle in \textit{NE} 4.7, is a mean between boasting and false modesty (\textgreek{ἀλαζονεία} and \textgreek{εἰρωνεία}).
Boasters claim admirable qualities that they lack or they exaggerate their share in those qualities; the \textit{eiron} disavows admirable qualities that they possess.
In this context, Aristotle says, ``The qualities that win reputation are the ones that these people especially disavow, as Socrates also used to do'' (\textit{NE} 4.7 in Irwin's translation).
This (unnamed) virtue, says Aristotle in \textit{NE} 4.7, is a mean between boasting and false modesty (\textgreek{ἀλαζονεία} and \textgreek{εἰρωνεία}).

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is not the style. it happens with other styles too. biblatex loads the localization files in the middle of the text. and it has empty lines you get a paragraph break. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1041

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for tracking this down. If you want to turn your comment into a brief answer, I'm happy to accept it. I already posted a link to GitHub for future Googlers who don't read comments, but you deserve the points. I assumed it was the two specific packages, but I should have checked BibLaTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know of a more elegant way to avoid these line breaks/spaces when reading the file? For now we're boxing the `\input` (which was actually done before, but I removed it), which doesn't feel great to me. I played around with `\endlinechar` but that still left some undesired spaces.

Comment: @moewe well latex reads in .fd files with `\nfss@catcodes`, but I don't know if the contents of the localization files is well-defined and well-behaved enough to allow this. Perhaps it would be safer if you record the missing language in the aux-file and load it at the begin of the next compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much for those ideas. I'll have a look at those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [pointed out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560329/a-phantom-linebreak-with-polyglossia-and-biblatex#comment1413192_560329), this was a bug in `biblatex` v3.15: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1041.

The problem was that `biblatex` would load `.lbx` localisation files on demand in the document body. Since `.lbx` files may contain blank lines, those would end up creating paragraph breaks in the document where the file was loaded.

In version 3.16 of `biblatex`, which was released on 2020-21-31 and is available now in both TeX live and MikTeX, `biblatex` no longer loads `.lbx` files in the document body. If a language hasn't been loaded already in the preamble, it will be requested in the `.aux` file and loaded in the next run.

If you are still having this issue, update your TeX system and make sure you have `biblatex` v3.16 and a matching Biber version installed.